# Angular UI Pagination loads home page instead of changing page content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Everytime I click on a new page (next or one of the numbered pages), it just redirects to the homepage [well the domain). I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what or where.

This is in my html view:

```
<ul id="results" class="profile-list">
    <li ng-repeat="profile in profiles track by profile.id" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-cloak ng-class="profile.role" class="profile clearfix">

        <div ng-switch="profile.role == 'company' || profile.role == 'school'">
            <div ng-switch-when="true">
                <?= $this->partial('index/_profile_badge_school_company.phtml') ?>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                <?= $this->partial('index/_profile_badge_student.phtml') ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
<uib-pagination ng-if="profiles.length > 0" total-items="resultCount" ng-model="$parent.currentPage" max-size="maxSize"
                class="pagination-sm" num-pages="numPages" ng-change="loadResults()"></uib-pagination>
```

This is part the controllers' js code:

```
$scope.profiles = [];
$scope.resultCount = 0;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 20;
$scope.maxSize = 5;
```

There are other parts, like the loadResults function, but I don't think you need to see those ?

**EDIT:**

```
CompApp.directory = angular.module('directory', ['stars', 'filters', 'ngRoute', 'debounce', 'myApp', 'LocalStorageModule', 'autocomplete', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
});
```

And pages are done with ZF1 routing (PHP). The current page follows like: module/controller/action path so: directory/index/index?types=profile,company

Comment: what kind of routing did you use? Usually it's happening to me, when my routes are bad, for example: in UI-route url: '/list/{id}', missing the id, or the 'list' word is misspeled, maybe you missing a trailing '/', so it's redirecting you to the default route.

Comment: I'm not familiar with zend, so i can't help you with it, but what comes in mind, is the same, so you have some route config problem, but with zend. C# mvc example : http://pastebin.com/5acp6Uqk. So basically when it can't match the route you have, it will redirect you to the default one.